# Join fetch on composite-id (embeded) not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Hibernate fetch fail for @ManyToOne of composite ID, the raison is that
during the resolvation of emded ids, entities are loaded directly from DB, not from the resultSet, or even from the session cache.

```
protected final Object resolveIdentifier(Serializable id, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {
        EntityPersister entityPersister = session.getFactory()
        .getEntityPersister( getAssociatedEntityName() );
        boolean isProxyUnwrapEnabled = unwrapProxy &&
                entityPersister.isInstrumented( session.getEntityMode() );      
            proxyOrEntity = loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(rs, i, persisters[i], descriptors[i].getRowIdAlias(), 
                            entityKey, lockModes[i], null, null, hydratedObjects, session);
                    return proxyOrEntity;
                }                           
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }
```

The result of that is if you load 100 records of an Entity with a composit ID of two other Entites, you will have : 1 + 2 * 100 Queries !

Comment: Can you provide more information such as the queries it does generate and how you are executing your query?

Comment: i add more explaination about the problem

Comment: fixed by modyfing org.hibernate.loader.Loader, org.hibernate.type.ComponentType and org.hibernate.type.EntityType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   org.hibernate.type.EntityType

   protected final Object resolveIdentifier(Serializable id, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {
        EntityPersister entityPersister = session.getFactory()
                        .getEntityPersister( getAssociatedEntityName() );
        boolean isProxyUnwrapEnabled = unwrapProxy &&
                                entityPersister.isInstrumented( session.getEntityMode() );      
        /**** first check the session cache *****/
        EntityKey entityKey = new EntityKey(id, 
                                entityPersister, session.getEntityMode() );
                    Object proxyOrEntity = session.getPersistenceContext().getEntity( entityKey );            
        if (proxyOrEntity!=null)
            return proxyOrEntity;
        /**** second check the fetchs of resultSet *****/
        try {
             if ( loader!=null && !rs.isClosed() ){         
                 final EntityAliases[] descriptors = loader.getEntityAliases_();                                    
                 String[] identifierAliases = (String[]) PrivateAccessor.getPrivateField( entityPersister, "identifierAliases", true);              
                 for (int i=0;i<descriptors.length;i++){
                    boolean founds = true;
                    for(int j=0;j<identifierAliases.length;j++){                                                       if (descriptors[i].getSuffixedKeyAliases().length!=identifierAliases.length)
                            founds = false;
                    else
                        if (!descriptors[i].getSuffixedKeyAliases()[j].toString().startsWith(identifierAliases[j]))
                        founds = false;                     
                    }       
                    if (!founds)
                     continue; 
    proxyOrEntity = loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(rs, i, persisters[i], descriptors[i].getRowIdAlias(), entityKey, lockModes[i], null, null, hydratedObjects, session);
            return proxyOrEntity;
            }                           
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HibernateException(e);
    }
    /***** old code *****/
        proxyOrEntity = session.internalLoad(
                getAssociatedEntityName(),
                id,
                eager,
                isNullable() && !isProxyUnwrapEnabled
            );

        if ( proxyOrEntity instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
            ( ( HibernateProxy ) proxyOrEntity ).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                        .setUnwrap( isProxyUnwrapEnabled );
        }

    return proxyOrEntity;
```